# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/converter/RsaKeyConverters

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

**I begin to learn spring and spring security and i have the following error. I have been following several guides and with all I have the same problem. The error is when I try to lift the application**

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/converter/RsaKeyConverters
        at org.springframework.security.config.crypto.RsaKeyConversionServicePostProcessor.pkcs8(RsaKeyConversionServicePostProcessor.java:89) ~[spring-security-config-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.config.crypto.RsaKeyConversionServicePostProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory(RsaKeyConversionServicePostProcessor.java:66) ~[spring-security-config-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:286) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:181) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:706) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.6.RELEASE]
        at com.myApplication.myApplication.main(myApplicationApplication.java:13) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) ~[myApplication-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) ~[myApplication-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51) ~[myApplication-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52) ~[myApplication-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.converter.RsaKeyConverters
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:92) ~[myApplication-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[na:na]
        ... 21 common frames omitted
```

**This is my pom.xml:**

```
        <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
<properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

        <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.14.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

**My application.class**

```
@EnableResourceServer
@SpringBootApplication
public class myApplicationApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(myApplicationApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**I'm a novice with spring and spring security so any help would be greatly appreciated.**

Comment: Which spring-security-oauth.version are you using? It's missing the definition of that param. The error seems due to incompatible jar version, so post all your pom, please

Comment: `${spring-security-jwt.version}` and `${spring-security-oauth.version}` should refer to some params or properties, so there should be also their definition, something like this `<properties>
<spring-security-oauth.version>5.3.6</spring-security-oauth.version>
</properties>` or are you passing them with maven command? Like `mvn install "-Dsomeproperty=propety value"`. If you want, post tutorial link, to understand it better

Comment: I just updated my pom.xml in the post

Comment: The tutorial: [link](https://medium.com/@dassum/securing-spring-boot-rest-api-with-json-web-token-and-jdbc-token-store-67558a7d6c29), just specify the spring boot version, so i looked for compatible versions

Comment: On the [Github](https://github.com/sumanentc/springboot-oauth-jwt) there's everything. Anyway, you can't use spring < 5 with java 11, so try to use java 1.8 or follow the tutorial

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to fix the problem by removing of from current building of spring-security-core version less than 5.2. It looks like it depends of this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

I reached that by removing old version spring-security-core from my project  POM here:

```
  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
<!--            <version>5.1.6.RELEASE</version>-->
        </dependency>
```

I have realized that: In effective-pom so different spring-security-core versions:

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
      <version>5.4.2</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.6.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

But  org.springframework.security.converter.RsaKeyConverters class was appeared since 5.2 version. You you can see that here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/commit/1c25fe26c9d0241f14f28705ec585aa5c9791ae1#diff-4412eaef26b0242873cc8a9dc5533fee75014866b296e2a3e791c98936607b26

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue while working with spring boot security
it was fixed by adding those to my dependencies in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version> -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Update spring security dependency

```
 <dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
  <version>5.4.2</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```